# Error while exluding MongoDataAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot

I've tried to exclude mongoDB autoconfiguration from a spring-boot project but i keep having that error:

```
Method mvcConversionService in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport required a bean named 'mongoTemplate' that could not be found.
```

Configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ChromeDataCoreApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ChromeDataCoreApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found that in my case I had an interface that was annotated with `@Repository` and even though nothing depended on it Spring Boot created it anyway and tried to connect to the Mongo database.

`WebMvcConfigurerComposite#addFormatters` tries to add `HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration` which, in turn, requires the `mongoTemplate` bean. To fix this I was able to put an annotation on my repository interface:

`@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "mongo.enabled", havingValue = "true")`

To remove the `HateoasAwareSpringWebConfiguration` bean from the list of delegates used in `addFormatters` the following can be added to your `@SpringBootApplication`:

`@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.class})`

Of course I also included the two classes for Mongo auto configuration:

`@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class, SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.class})`

I should note that once the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation was added to the repository interface the `SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.class` was no longer required.